# Make an editable grid using controller of mvc5 and view and model of backbone.js

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell me how to make an editable grid using mvc5 controller and the view and model of backbone.js. I'm coding using C#.net. The user should be able to enter data in the grid and save it in database.

If anyone knows any link then please share

Comment: please mention code you've tried so far!

Comment: Its new to me.. So i even dont knw how to start. I know how to display a grid on clicking search button but dont know how to make it editable(If i want to add new values)

Comment: This link might help ya, http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd7c2e/create-an-editable-webgrid-in-mvc4-to-implement-crud-operati/

Answer (score 0):

In render function

```
render: function () {

  //thead
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     data = [[addRow1 = ''], [addRow2 = ''], [addRow3 = ''], [addRow4 = ''], [addRow5 = '']]
  };
  this.$el.empty();
  this.$el.html(this.template);
  var totalResults = data.length + 1;
  var oTable = this.$('#js-charge-dt').iidsBasicDataGrid({
      scrollX: true,
      //scrollY: 320,
      "scrollCollapse": true,
      //"pagingType": "full_numbers",
      "iTotalDisplayRecords": totalResults,
      "bFilter": false,
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bSearchable": false,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bPaginate": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      useFloater: false,
      iTotalDisplayRecords: 30,

      aoColumns: [

      { "sTitle": "Customer No", "sClass": "CustNo" },
      { "sTitle": "TC", "sClass": "trans" },
      { "sTitle": "DC", "sClass": "dc" },
      { "sTitle": "IC", "sClass": "ic" },

      { "sTitle": "Notes", "sClass": "notes" }

      ],
      "aaData": data,

      createdRow: function (row, data, index) {

          this.$('td.CustNo', row).html('<input type="text" size="15">');
          this.$('td.trans', row).html('<select style="width: 250px;" class="tc"></select>');
          this.$('td.dc', row).html('<input type="text" size="5">');
          this.$('td.ic', row).html('<input type="text" size="10">');

          this.$('td.notes', row).html('<input type="text" size="2000">');
      }

  });

},
```